# Override specific admin css files in Django

Tags: python, css, django, django-admin

Overriding admin templates is as easy as creating a folder `admin` in your templates directory and copying whatever template files you'd like to override into it. I simply want to play with the admin style sheets however, so I made a folder `admin` in my static files folder and put `css/base.css` into it. Unlike the templates solution, this doesn't seem to work.

So is there any way to override individual css files for `django.contrib.admin` in the same way that you can override templates? If nay, what would be the best solution for overriding css files? I'm looking for a solution short of copying all the admin media files into my project and changing admin's static directory

Comment: Do you want to overwrite the CSS for all pages in the admin or just for particular change lists or models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm looking for a solution short of copying all the admin media files into my project and changing admin's static directory

I don't think there is really an alternative. You copy the media files into a new directory and while you start the server pass the `adminmedia` command line argument, like

```
python manage.py runserver --adminmedia=./myadminmedia
```

In any case, when you run it on production server, the admin media has to be served from a good static serving server, for which, you can point this new path.

Reference from the Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---adminmedia

Comment: Also `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py: error: no such option: --adminmedia`

Comment: Ok, so the `--aminmedia` deal didn't work **at all**, but I ended up just configuring Apache for development anyway, which makes this answer the closest one.

Comment: Here is the reference for --adminmedia: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---adminmedia

Answer (score 10):

What I'm doing to achieve that is to override `base_site.html` template like this:

```
{% block blockbots %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/css/my_admin.css" />
{{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

I put the CSS in `blockbots`instead of `extrahead` to be sure that is loaded at the end, so it will override all others CSS.

Comment: In recent versions of django you can use the `extrastyle` block instead.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can hack your urls.py file and point only a single media URL to be served from a local folder while the others are served from the Django directory(in development mode).